# Php value multiply by row count of table

Tags: php

hello guyz im (Rain) i am new to programming (php). I want to sum the value from database and multiply it by the row in html(php form table) with the same id , it is confusing so ill give  an output .

what i get is

```
A. Sample 1
 1. 100 = 200
 2. 100 = 200

B. Sample 2
 1. 100 = 200
 2. 100 = 200
 3. 100 = 200

B. Sample 3
 1. 100 = 200
 2. 100 = 200
 3. 100 = 200
 4. 100 = 200
```

and what i want to get is

```
B. Sample 2
 1. 100 = 300
 2. 100 = 300
 3. 100 = 300

C. Sample 3
 1. 100 = 400
 2. 100 = 400
 3. 100 = 400
 4. 100 = 400
```

form

```
<?php echo $row["points"];?>
<?php $s=$row["points"]; +  $b=$row["points"]; echo $s + $b;?>
```

Comment: value multiple by the count of row so ex. value = 2 and table row = 3  2x3 = 6 , table row = 10   2x10 = 20

Comment: Show this data `sum the value from database and multiply it by the row in html`

Comment: yes that what i want to get

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is what you are looking for, but my best guess is this:

Example:

```
<?php
$samples = array(
    array(100, 150),
    array(100, 150, 200),
    array(100, 150, 200, 250)
);

$i = 1;
foreach($samples as $sample)
{
    $rows = sizeof($sample);
    echo "Sample $i: <br>";

    $j = 1;
    foreach($sample as $row)
    {
        $val = $row * $rows;
        echo "$j. $row = $val <br>";
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Sample 1:
1. 100 = 200
2. 150 = 300

Sample 2:
1. 100 = 300
2. 150 = 450
3. 200 = 600

Sample 3:
1. 100 = 400
2. 150 = 600
3. 200 = 800
4. 250 = 1000
```

Comment: i try to apply the code then it show "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when i use my variable instead of the one 'samples'

Comment: i finally got it right thanks for that example sir Trevor

Answer (score 0):

i did this

```
<?php
        $samples = array(
        array($row["points"]),
        );
        foreach($samples as $sample)
        {
        $row["points"];
        $rows = sizeof($sample);
        foreach($sample as $row)
        {
        $val = $row * $rows;
        }   
        }
        ?>
```

and now i need the rows to count  the table row generated by database
ex. $val = $row * value(count of table row )